# Expected Function or variable vb6.0

Tags: vb6

Hello i am coding in Visual Basic 6.0 and i have this error, i am trying to make a button inserting data in database.

```
Expected Function or variable
```

This is my code

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
With ConString.Recordset.AddNew
 !ID = txtID
 !Emri = txtEmri
 !Mbiemri = txtMbiemri
 !Datelindja = txtData
 !Telefon = !txtTelefon
 !Gjinia = gender
 !Punesuar = job
 !Martese = cmbMartese
 !Vendlindja = txtVendlindje
 End With
End Sub

txtID is textbox
txtEmri is textbox
txtMbiemri is textbox
txtData is date picker
txtTelefon is textbox
gender is a string that takes value if a radio button is clicked
job is an integer if a checkbox is clicked
cmbMartese is combo box
txtVendlindje is textbox
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line in your code is showing the error? - I assume the !Telefon line shouldn't have the second exclamation mark to the right of the equals sign in it and the descriptions below the End Sub aren't part of your code!

Comment: @JohnEason i dont know just shows this paragraph as an error

Comment: I assume you're running in the IDE so it must stop on a line and bring up the error, otherwise how would you know that the error is in the code that you've posted?

Comment: @JohnEason it stops here Private Sub Command1_Click()

Comment: Ok. It looks as if your first 'With' line is wrong. It should be two lines: 'With ConString.Recordset' on the first line and '.AddNew' (with the leading period) on a line on its own below. If that doesn't sort it I'm afraid I'm going to bed now so someone else will have to look at it!

Answer (score 2):

@JohnEason gave you the right answer. But there's another error in the line `!Telefon = !txtTelefon`, if I'm not mistaken. It should read `!Telefon = txtTelefon`, i.e. without the exclamation mark in front of txtTelefon.

I'm also not a big fan of that coding style. I prefer to *not* rely on default properties, but instead "spell out" the whole term, e.g.

```
With ConString.Recordset
 .AddNew
 !ID = txtID.Text
 !Emri = txtEmri.Text
 !Mbiemri = txtMbiemri.Text
 !Datelindja = txtData.Text
 !Telefon = txtTelefon.Text
 ' Since VB6 doesn't provide Intellisense for variables, I prefer to use some
 ' kind of hungarian notation for variable names, in this case sGender or strGender for a string variable
 !Gjinia = gender
 ' Same here: iJob or intJob for an integer variable
 !Punesuar = job
 ' You need to specify that you want the selected item of a combobox
 !Martese = cmbMartese.List(cmbMartese.ListIndex)
 !Vendlindja = txtVendlindje.Text
 ' If you're done setting column values and don't do so somewhere else, 
 ' you also need to add a .Update statement here in order to finish the 
 ' .AddNew action and actually persist the data to the database.
 ' .Update
 End With
End Sub
```

As pointed out below by @JohnEason, there's also potentially an `.Update` statement missing within the `With/End With` block

Comment: I did mention the !TextTelefon error but also forgot to mention that there should really be an .Update statement before the final 'End With' line. I agree about the coding style!

Comment: Ah, yes, in your first comment. Apologies - my bad. As for the potentially missing `.Update` ... it may or may not be somewhere else deeper down the line _(though I doubt that)_.